# While Loop inside ASYNC AWAIT

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have some code that continuously updates a series of objects via network calls looks like this.  I was wondering if this is bad practice and if there might be a better way. I cant use Set Interval as the time between `MakeAsyncCall` replies is variable and can cause a leak if the time to make the call is longer than the delay.  I will be using this info to update a UI. Will this cause blocking? What are your thoughts? Let me know if you need more info.

```
let group = [item1, item2, item3];

// Start Loop
readForever(group, 100);

// Function to Delay X ms
const delay = ms => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    });
};

// Function to continuously Make Calls
const readForever = async (group, ms) => {
    while(true) {
        // Make Async Call
        for (let item of group) {
            await MakeAsyncCall(item);
        }

        // Wait X ms Before Processing Continues
        await delay(ms);
    }
};
```

Comment: As an aside, delay could be written as `const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given code won't cause any UI blocking. And is a valid way to update the UI continually.

Instead of a loop you could write it that way:

```
const readForever = async (group, ms) => {
  // Make Async Call
  for (let item of group) {
    await MakeAsyncCall(item);
  }

  // Wait X ms Before Processing Continues
  await delay(ms);

  if (true) { // not needed, but there you could define an end condition
    return readForever(group, ms);
  }
};
```

In addition to the comment about the `delay` function:
You could directly pass the `resolve` to `setTimeout`, and because you do not cancel the Timeout anywhere you do not need to store the result `setTimeout` in a variable.

```
const delay = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

Comment: Awesome.  Do you have any other potential ways of doing this. I like learning new ways to skin a cat so to speak.

Comment: @canaanseaton added an alternative

Comment: The recursive solution might lead to a stack overflow though if the engine does not support tail call optimisation.